# php json_encode euro symbol for android

Tags: java, php, android, json, encoding

I am loading data in an android app from a php service.
In php i use json_encode to convert my data.
Now i have a string with a `€` character in it.
`json_encode` converts this to `\u0080`, but as far as i know the actual correct unicode should be `\u20AC`.
Usually thats not a problem but the `Droid Sans` Font does only render `\u20AC` as the euro symbol.

My question: Is there a way to make the `€` character convert correctly (i dont care if thats in `Java`or in `PHP`, although i would prefer a php solution) **without** using any string replaces or regex etc..
replacing seems ugly and there might be more symbols that dont get converted properly that i dont know of yet.

Comment: Where does your Euro character come from? 0080 sounds like it's coming from a non-UTF8 encoding

Comment: Post your PHP and your Java code. Encoding needs to be spot-on in both.

Comment: \u0080 would correspond to an html entity &#x80/&#128, which'd be the euro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\u0080` means that the input character was `\x80` which is the Euro sign in **Windows-1252**. So I assume your string is encoded in this charset, then you should convert it to UTF-8 because `json_encode` only works with UTF-8 input:

```
$string = iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8', $string);
```

Comment: yeah, thats it, so utf8_encode does not work on 1252 encoded strings? because i was using it

Comment: yes, utf8_encode converts ISO 8859-1 to UTF-8, nothing more. PHP and its special-purpose functions... ;-)